# can't to plot two labels for two lines on the graph from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot2 for my project and I'm trying to plot some line graphs.

I tried different command to add labels (names) and colours also legends for my lines that are from two datasets.

Can someone teach me a bit on how to work it out?

thank you!

Here is my current R script.

```
library(ggplot2)

potsexass <- ggplot() + 
            geom_line(data=hkviolentcrimeperpop, aes(x=violent_crime, y = indecent_assault)) + 
            geom_line(data=londonviolentcrimeperpop, aes(x=violentcrimes, y= other_sexual_offences)) +
            geom_point(data=hkviolentcrimeperpop, aes(x=violent_crime, y = indecent_assault)) + 
            geom_point(data=londonviolentcrimeperpop, aes(x=violentcrimes, y= other_sexual_offences))+
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2011, to = 2020, by = 1))+
            xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of Cases") +  labs(title="Indecent or Sexual Assaults", size = 15)
```

[image]

I have tried below three command but still nothing on my graph.

```
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(directlabels)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide some sample data to reproduce your codes? You can do that like `dput(hkviolentcrimeperpop)` .

Comment: It's best to combine the two datasets first into one, listing the years, types of assault, and counts. Then rely on that to map colours onto types of assault.